# show the log of a hidden git SHA on bash

Tags: git

I did an reset of my branch. Now I can't see the commit which is done after the current commit.

Yes, I know

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

but how can I see an date or a log info of the shown SHA codes?

Comment: Can you not get back via `git reflog`?

Comment: yes! thats the command i'm searching for... sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 1):

To get reflog logs with dates you can use the `-g` option to log:

```
git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty="%h %ad %s"
```